# TLS support for LDAP in Thunderbird

Tags: ssl, ldap, thunderbird

I am trying to connect to an LDAP address book using Thunderbird (v31.5) using an encrypted connection. If I try an unencrypted connection, this works flawlessly, but as soon as I configure the LDAP server to require TLS to bind I can no longer connect using Thunderbird.

If I do not enable the SSL checkbox, the server simply refuses any search operation as Thunderbird does not seem to issue any StartTLS equivalent (ie `ldap_start_tls_s()`). The server issues the error `send_ldap_result: err=13 matched="" text="TLS confidentiality required"`, Thunderbird remains silent (with full logging enabled)

If I do check it, Thunderbird indicates no error either, and the server shows `connection_read(25): TLS accept failure error=-1 id=1063, closing` followed by `conn=1063 fd=25 closed (TLS negotiation failure)`.

I tried manually importing the server's certificate, even though it is valid and the root CA is already included in Thunderbird's CA list.

Other applications work fine, e.g. performing an `ldapsearch` from the same system as Thunderbird (either using the `-ZZ` option or an ldaps:// URI) or using Apache Directory.

Does anyone know how to make Thunderbird issue STARTTLS, or if not possible fix the TLS negation failure?

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me.
I was using the wrong port.

Long story here: https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-rancher-extra-catalogs/issues/18

Thunderbird 78 did not say anything and only asked for the password even if it was not connecting to the ldap server.

Not the best error handling in the world better is to use an external tool to inspect the packets on the network.

Solution: use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and inspect if the communication is working or not.